# How does Send() works in Orbeon forms?

Tags: xml, forms, xhtml, orbeon

First of all thanks to Orbeon developers for such a beautiful form builder. I have created my own forms, Now on click of save button I don't want to save the form data (Field inputs) into the database. I need to send the form data in to JSP/Servlet page. For that I have created a send button in the form detail page, By modifying the following code in `properties-form-runner.xml`

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.*.*">
        clear save-final review send
</property>
```

Then I modified the `properties-local.xml` file as follows,

```
<properties xmlnss="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
xmlnsh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlnsf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
xmlnsxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
xmlnsbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
xmlnsxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner">
<property as="xs:NMTOKENS" name="oxf.xforms.logging.debug">
document model submission control event action analysis server html process
</property>
<property as="xs:NMTOKENS" name="oxf.xforms.logging.error" value="submission-error-body"/>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*" replace="all" method="GET" id="fr-workflow-send-submission"
 value='require-valid
        then send("http://localhost:8080/orbeon-4.8.0.201502041339-CE/xforms-jsp/guess-the-number/index.jsp")
        then navigate("/success")
        recover navigate("/failure")'/> 
</properties>
```

Then After creating the build and fill the respective form and on click of the "Submit" button, I am getting the following error. `Orbeon Forms - Page Not Found`

The Log details are as follows,

```
2015-02-04 19:39:26,051 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                 start submission {id: "fr-send-submission-none"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,051 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                   optimized dispatching {name: "xforms-submit-serialize", target: "fr-send-submission-none", native handlers called: "0"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,051 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                   start connecting {type: "regular"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,051 INFO  lifecycle  - event: {"request": "93", "session": "2C12D5E5336D383277FDFA2BA49B9453", "source": "service", "message": "start: handle", "path": "/fr/orbeon/bookshelf/", "method": "POST"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,051 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/orbeon/bookshelf/ - Received request
2015-02-04 19:39:26,066 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - not found {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "POST", path: "/fr/orbeon/bookshelf/"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,082 INFO  PageFlowControllerProcessor  - not found {controller: "oxf:/page-flow.xml", method: "POST", path: "/fr/orbeon/bookshelf/"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,114 INFO  ProcessorService  - /fr/orbeon/bookshelf/ - Timing: 63
2015-02-04 19:39:26,115 INFO  lifecycle  - event: {"request": "93", "session": "2C12D5E5336D383277FDFA2BA49B9453", "source": "service", "message": "end: handle", "time": "64 ms"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,117 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                   end connecting {time (ms): "66"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,117 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                   start handling result
2015-02-04 19:39:26,117 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                     evaluated model variables {count: "4"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,120 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                     xf:insert - inserted nodes {count: "3"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,120 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                     xf:insert - inserted nodes {count: "1"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,120 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                     xf:delete - removed nodes {count: "1"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,120 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                   end handling result {time (ms): "3"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,121 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                 end submission {time (ms): "70"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,121 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                 evaluated model variables {count: "4"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                 xforms-submit-error - setting throwable {throwable: "
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |xf:submission for submission id: fr-send-submission-none, error code received when submitting instance: 404           |
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |Exception: org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsSubmissionException                                                 |
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|getReplacer                   |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 729|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        | 107|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |rg.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission$1|call                          |RegularSubmission.java        |  77|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.BaseSubmission    |submitCallable                |BaseSubmission.scala          |  89|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.RegularSubmission |connect                       |RegularSubmission.java        | 130|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|doSubmit                      |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 460|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.orbeon.oxf.xforms.submission.XFormsModelSubmission|performDefaultAction          |XFormsModelSubmission.java    | 292|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                | 125|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  74|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |ch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  74|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.util.Logging$class                  |withDebug                     |Logging.scala                 |  50|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withDebug                     |Dispatch.scala                |  23|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |Dispatch.scala                |  74|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  73|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$$anonfun$dispatchEvent$1|apply                         |Dispatch.scala                |  73|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |withEvent$1                   |Dispatch.scala                |  38|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.event.Dispatch$              |dispatchEvent                 |Dispatch.scala                |  72|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAPI$            |send                          |XFormsAPI.scala               | 275|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.xforms.action.XFormsAPI$            |sendThrowOnError              |XFormsAPI.scala               | 292|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |oxf.fr.process.FormRunnerActions$$anonfun$trySend$1|apply                         |FormRunnerActions.scala       | 277|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |oxf.fr.process.FormRunnerActions$$anonfun$trySend$1|apply                         |FormRunnerActions.scala       | 206|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |scala.util.Try$                                    |apply                         |Try.scala                     | 161|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.fr.process.FormRunnerActions$class  |trySend                       |FormRunnerActions.scala       | 206|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.fr.process.SimpleProcess$           |trySend                       |SimpleProcess.scala           |  35|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |rmRunnerActions$$anonfun$AllowedFormRunnerActions$8|apply                         |FormRunnerActions.scala       |  40|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |rmRunnerActions$$anonfun$AllowedFormRunnerActions$8|apply                         |FormRunnerActions.scala       |  40|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |ssInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$$anonfun$runAction$1$3|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 139|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |ssInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$$anonfun$runAction$1$3|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 134|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.util.Logging$class                  |withDebug                     |Logging.scala                 |  50|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.fr.process.SimpleProcess$           |withDebug                     |SimpleProcess.scala           |  35|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |n.oxf.fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$|runAction$1                   |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 134|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |n.oxf.fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$|org$orbeon$oxf$fr$process$Proc|ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 195|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |rpreter$ProcessRuntime$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$apply$8|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 161|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |rpreter$ProcessRuntime$$anonfun$11$$anonfun$apply$8|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 161|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |scala.util.Success                                 |flatMap                       |Try.scala                     | 200|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |ocess.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$$anonfun$11|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 161|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |ocess.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$$anonfun$11|apply                         |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 158|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |n.oxf.fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$|withStackFrame                |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 104|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |n.oxf.fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$|runGroupRest$1                |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 157|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |n.oxf.fr.process.ProcessInterpreter$ProcessRuntime$|runGroup$1                    |ProcessInterpreter.scala      | 149|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |---8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<--------8<---|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |nServlet$$anonfun$service$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  79|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |nServlet$$anonfun$service$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |nServlet$$anonfun$service$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.util.ScalaUtils$                    |withRootException             |ScalaUtils.scala              |  83|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet$$anonfun$service$1|apply                         |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  72|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.util.DynamicVariable                |withValue                     |DynamicVariable.scala         |  42|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.OrbeonServlet               |service                       |OrbeonServlet.scala           |  71|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet                     |service                       |HttpServlet.java              | 722|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 305|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 210|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |LimiterFilter.scala           |  85|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  85|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  85|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.logging.LifecycleLogger$            |withEvent                     |LifecycleLogger.scala         | 124|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1|apply$mcV$sp                  |LimiterFilter.scala           |  84|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  78|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1$$anonfun$apply$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  78|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.logging.LifecycleLogger$            |withEvent                     |LifecycleLogger.scala         | 124|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |rbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  78|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |rbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter$$anonfun$doFilter$1|apply                         |LimiterFilter.scala           |  72|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |scala.Option                                       |foreach                       |Option.scala                  | 236|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.orbeon.oxf.servlet.LimiterFilter               |doFilter                      |LimiterFilter.scala           |  72|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |internalDoFilter              |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 243|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain    |doFilter                      |ApplicationFilterChain.java   | 210|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve      |invoke                        |StandardWrapperValve.java     | 225|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve      |invoke                        |StandardContextValve.java     | 169|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase|invoke                        |AuthenticatorBase.java        | 472|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve         |invoke                        |StandardHostValve.java        | 168|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve        |invoke                        |ErrorReportValve.java         |  98|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve          |invoke                        |AccessLogValve.java           | 927|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve       |invoke                        |StandardEngineValve.java      | 118|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter        |service                       |CoyoteAdapter.java            | 407|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor   |process                       |AbstractHttp11Processor.java  | 999|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |e.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler|process                       |AbstractProtocol.java         | 565|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor|run                           |JIoEndpoint.java              | 309|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker     |runTask                       |ThreadPoolExecutor.java       | 885|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker     |run                           |ThreadPoolExecutor.java       | 907|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     |java.lang.Thread                                   |run                           |Thread.java                   | 619|
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 ERROR XFormsServer  -                     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                 start dispatching {name: "xforms-submit-error", target: "fr-send-submission-none"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                   start handler {name: "xforms-submit-error", phase: "target", observer: "fr-send-submission-none"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                     interpreter - start executing {action name: "xf:setvalue"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       xf:setvalue - setting instance value {source: "setvalue", old value: "false", new value: "", instance: "fr-persistence-instance"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-value-changed", target: "fr-persistence-instance"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start handler {name: "xxforms-value-changed", phase: "target", observer: "fr-persistence-instance"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                           interpreter - not executing {action name: "xf:action", condition type: "if", reason: "condition evaluated to 'false'", condition: "name(event('node')) = 'data-status' and event('old-value') != event('new-value')"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end handler {time (ms): "0"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0", regular handlers called: "1", native handlers called: "0"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                     interpreter - end executing {time (ms): "0", action name: "xf:setvalue"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                   end handler {time (ms): "0"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                 end dispatching {time (ms): "0", regular handlers called: "1", native handlers called: "1"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,149 DEBUG XFormsServer  -               end dispatching {time (ms): "119", regular handlers called: "1", native handlers called: "0"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,165 DEBUG XFormsServer  -             end process: running action {time (ms): "152", result: "failure"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,165 DEBUG XFormsServer  -             process: combining with then {action: "ActionNode(navigate,Map(None -> /success))"}
2015-02-04 19:39:26,165 DEBUG XFormsServer  -             process: combining with recover {action: "ActionNode(navigate,Map(None -> /failure))"}
```

Also I have the following queries,

1) How it will send the data (In which format)?
2) How do we get the values in servelt/JSP?
3) Is it possible to send form data over different server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by editing the configuration in `properties-local.xml` as follows,

```
<property
  as="xs:string"
  name="oxf.fr.detail.process.send.*.*"
  value='require-valid
         then send(uri = "http://localhost:9090/ServletAction/demoClass", method="POST", content="metadata")
         then navigate("http://localhost:8080/orbeon/xforms-jsp/guess-the-number/index.jsp")
         recover navigate("http://localhost:8080/orbeon/xforms-jsp/flickr-search/index.jsp")'/>
```

In the servelt through request InputStream I am able to get the form instance in the Post method.